# Iterate over specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

How can I iterate over a list containing a subset of the columns in my dataframe?

Example:

df columns = a,b,c,d,e

```
my_list <- c("a","b","c")
```

If I try:

```
for (i in my_list){
   print(df$i)  
}
```

I obtain as many `NULL` as there are values in my_list. I need to solve this problem in order to apply some changes to the dataframe columns present in my_list.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your iteration?

Comment: You need to use `df[[i]]` not `df$i`